# Git diff --patience not working

Tags: git, git-diff

I don't know why, but the git patience algorithm is not working in my case.
I found nothing about that on google, that patience is not working.

I set patience to default in the git global config and I also tried the command *git diff --patience file*.

The diff looks always like this:

```
        return null;
+   }
+   
+   public void mymethod() {
+       // some code here
    }
```

And I expect this:

```
        return null;
    }
+   
+   public void mymethod() {
+       // some code here
+   }
```

Did I overlook something?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit and git version 1.9.3.

EDIT: Expected behavior of git diff patience algorithm: http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/73318.html

Comment: Why do reject that (perfectly sensible) diff as "wrong"?  Why do you think `patience` would be any different?

Comment: According to git diff patience explanations like this one (http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/73318.html) i expect that the diff looks like the second code snippet. Bracket is bracket, but in the reality the first closing bracket is not that one that belongs to mymethod().

Comment: Thanks for that link, it adds valuable context to your question.  My understanding of patience diff did not address this example.

Comment: Hi, the patience algorithm is working correctly for a _git merge --strategy-option patience sourceBranch_. But not for git-diff. I can't find any difference in the diff between _git diff_ and _git diff --patience_. These two diffs are the same. Why is this option not working? Anybody any pointers?